# Is there a characterization of associative algebra in terms of structure constants?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

For finite-dimensional algebras one has that an algebra is commutative if and only if the structure constants (in a given basis) are symmetric in the subscripts, $C^k_{ij} = C^k_{ji}$ (where $C^k_{ij}$ is defined by $e_ie_j = C^k_{ij}e_k$ for $E = \{e_i\}$ a basis for the algebra, and where I've used the summation convention).

My question is, **is there a similar characterization for associative algebras**? A cursory glance at Wikipedia showed nothing, and my book didn't mention anything either.

Per @RobArthan's suggestion, I have obtained the following (I use capital letters for the elements of the algebra as that's what my book does):

> If an algebra is associative then one of its bases is associative, which occurs if and only if
> $$C^l_{ij}C^m_{lk}E_m = (C^l_{ij}E_l)E_k = (E_iE_j)E_k = E_i(E_jE_k) = E_iC^l_{jk}E_l = C^l_{jk}C^m_{il}E_m,$$
> which, given the linear independence of the $E_m$, occurs if and only if $C^l_{ij}C^m_{lk} = C^l_{jk}C^m_{il}$ for all $i,j,k,m$.

I can't make much sense of this though. $l$ is a dummy variable being summed over. Perhaps there's some phrasing in terms of cyclic permuations?

Comment: So what did you try to do for yourself? As a hint, if the multiplication is associative for the generators it is associative on the whole algebra (you need to prove that). Now you need tow write out what $e_i(e_je_k) = (e_ie_j)e_k$ means in terms of the multiplication defined by the structure constants.

Comment: Will try that right now, thanks @RobArthan . I often struggle to come up with the lemmas myself, but am decent at proving them once asserted. Obviously that creativity is a skill that needs to be worked on.

Comment: @RobArthan I have obtained the statement given in the OP. I can't make much sense of it though in words. Would you be able to give an interpretation?

Comment: It's using the [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). I don't know what the $E_i$ etc. that you have introduced mean. Focus on the basis elements $e_i$ and write out what $e_i(e_je_k) = (e_ie_j)e_k$ means using the structure constants.

Comment: I used capital letters but $E_i \equiv e_i$. Same thing is meant. I have given the conclusion in my edit, I am just trying to udnerstand what it means in a simple way like "symmetric in the subscripts" for the commutative case. @RobArthan

Comment: You just have to figure out what the notation is telling you. Try working through what is going on in dimensions 1 and 2.

Comment: If I write $C^l_{ij}C^m_{lk} =C^m_{il} C^l_{jk}$ then there's some weird interpretation of, given the LHS, swapping the superscripts and then associating the first and second subscripts in each pair respectively with each other? Would you be able to give a hint? @RobArthan

Comment: Hint: write down the relevant matrices in a small example. E.g., for dimension 2.

Comment: I don't follow, these structure constants are objects with three indices -- how am I to make sense of them as matrices? @RobArthan

Comment: I thought it would be simpler to post an answer. I'll leave it you to identify where matrices come in.

Answer (score 2):

To show that an algebra $\cal A$ with basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is associative, it is sufficient to show that $(e_ie_j)e_k = e_i(e_je_k)$ for any three indices $i$, $j$ and $k$. (I leave this as an exercise.)

So now assume we are given structure constants $C_{ij}^k$ for the algebra. I.e., the $C_{ij}^k$ are constants such that for any $i, j$:

$$
e_ie_j = \sum_{s=1}^n C_{ij}^s e_s
$$

(I'm avoiding the Einstein summation convention and putting in the $\sum$ signs.)

So, we have:

$$
(e_ie_j)e_k = \left(\sum_{s=1}^n C_{ij}^s e_s\right)e_k = \sum_{s=1}^n C_{ij}^s e_se_k = \sum_{s=1}^nC_{ij}^s\left(\sum_{t=1}^nC_{sk}^te_t\right)
=\sum_{t=1}^n \left(\sum_{s=1}^nC_{ij}^sC_{sk}^t\right) e_t
 \tag*{(1)}
$$
and
$$
e_i(e_je_k) = e_i\left(\sum_{s=1}^n C_{jk}^s e_s\right) = \sum_{s=1}^n C_{jk}^s e_ie_s = \sum_{s=1}^nC_{jk}^s\left(\sum_{t=1}^nC_{it}^se_t\right) =
\sum_{t=1}^n  \left(\sum_{s=1}^nC_{is}^tC_{jk}^s\right) e_t
\tag*{(2)}
$$

So equating coefficients in the rightmost formulas in (1) and (2), $\cal A$ is associative iff the following holds for any indices $i$, $j$, $k$ and $t$:
$$
\sum_{s=1}^nC_{ij}^sC_{sk}^t = \sum_{s=1}^nC_{is}^tC_{jk}^s
$$

Comment: I think I follow, and I think your result comports with the one I gave in a comment (though I used the summation convention). But I still don't see an interpretation in terms of matrices. If I neglect the superscripts (to reduce the constants to two dimensions) then there is no common subscript over which to sum. If I neglect one of the subscripts, I'm at a loss as to which one should be neglected? Would you be able to elaborate on how you look at that final answer and interpret it in terms of matrix multiplication?

Comment: Please ignore my point about matrices if it's not helping you.

Comment: But I get everything else. If you have an interpretation in terms of matrices I would be eager to hear it.

Comment: For a fixed $i$, the structure constants $C_{ij}^s$ give the matrix representation of the linear transformation $v \mapsto e_iv$.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow how $\sum_{s=1}^nC_{ij}^sC_{sk}^t = \sum_{s=1}^nC_{is}^tC_{jk}^s$ can be thought of as matrix multiplication. On the LHS, $s$ (which is being summed over) indexes the rows in the first factor and indexes the matrix in the second factor. On the RHS $s$ indexes the columns in the first factor and the rows in the second (in this case, the matrix multiplication makes sense).

Comment: All I wrote was "write down the relevant matrices", i.e., the matrices $C^s_{ij}$ for each fixed $i$ that represent multiplication on the left by $e_i$, because that is how I think of the structure constants: they give you the matrix representations of multiplication by the basis elements.

Comment: I see I see. But, to confirm, there is no interpretation in terms of matrix multiplication?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.